# How do I run `Observable` in a separate thread?

Tags: multithreading, scala, reactive-programming, rx-java

I use RxJava in Scala project and say I have this simple `Observable`:

```
Observable[String](observer => while (true) observer onNext "hi")
  .subscribe(v => println(v))

println("hello")
```

I will never get to "hello" message because `while` blocks a thread. How can I run my `Observable` in a separate thread to avoid blocking?

==================================

I was thinking `observeOn` could help but it does not. Running this:

```
val s = rx.lang.scala.schedulers.NewThreadScheduler.apply

Observable[String](observer => while (true) observer onNext "hi")
  .observeOn(s).subscribe(v => println(v))

println("hello")
```

...still does not print "hello". I guess adding `observeOn` makes `OnNext` to be called in a separate thread but not a `while` block itself?

==================================

I could of course wrap `while` in a `Future`:

```
Observable[String](observer => Future { while (true) observer onNext "hi" })
  .subscribe(v => println(v))

println("test") // "test" gets printed
```

But perhaps there are more rx-idiomatic ways of doing this exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `subscribeOn`. E.g.,

```
Observable[String](observer => while (true) observer onNext "hi").subscribeOn(s)
  .subscribe(v => println(v))
```

`subscribeOn` will call the `subscribe` function in the `Scheduler`, while `observeOn` will dispatch the messages to the `Scheduler`.